# django - queryset with extra method returns empty, count() says otherwise

Tags: django

Here is a related manager I wrote:

```
class PortfolioItemManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def extended(self): 

       return self.extra(select = {'current_price':'current_price', 'current_value':'current_price*quantity', 'gain':'current_price*quantity - cost'},
                      tables = ['pm_core_contract', ],
                      where = ['pm_core_contract.id = pm_core_portfolioitem.contract_id', ]
               )
```

Here are the results that stumps me:

```
In [10]: PortfolioItem.objects.extended()
Out[10]: []
In [11]: PortfolioItem.objects.extended().count()
Out[11]: 402
```

Result from count() is correct. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** The generated SQL is correct and can be executed against the db directly.

**EDIT2:** The issue stems from the last 2 select arguments, which feature arithmetic operations.

Comment: Please give us your PortfolioItem structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have just figured out the problem. Thanks go to Alex, whose comment has sparked the idea:

The PortfolioItem model has the properties `current_value` and `current_gain`, which I have been trying to replace with calculated SQL fields. It was my mistake to name one of the extra() method's select fields 'current_value' without removing the property, as that led to the model having two fields with the same name. When I did away with that overlapping, everything became OK. Lesson is learned.